# How to do changes to the value which is being validated in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there a way to manipulate the value of a String which is being validated in Spring boot validator?

```
public class EmailEncodedValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<EmailEncoded, String> {

    private static final Pattern EMAIL_ENCODED = Pattern
            .compile("^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+&#64;[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$");

    @Override
    public void initialize(EmailEncoded arg0) {
        // deliberate

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        Matcher matcher = EMAIL_ENCODED.matcher(value);
        if (matcher.matches()) {

            value.replaceAll("&#64;", "@");//do something like this to the original value passed
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Validator must not change validated value!

Comment: StanislavL -Thanks.